# The chart is giving me an "argument is not interpretable as logical" error

Tags: r, shiny

I am using googlevis to render my chart and I don't understand why they give me the error

The csv looks like this:
month,apples,melon,cherries,pomegranate,bananas,kivi,avocado
January,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
February,12,10,7,6,10,8,9
March,14,4,2,12,8,5,5
April,16,8,6,8,14,13,12
May,10,8,6,17,8,9,2
June,15,20,14,8,6,4,3
July,22,14,18,9,20,8,5
August,8,9,12,15,10,8,9
September,8,12,12,4,5,1,2
October,12,7,5,3,10,4,1
November,6,7,9,8,5,4,2
December,12,1,3,4,10,5,2

```
library(shiny)
library(googleVis)
Book1 <- read.csv("Book1.csv")

 ui <- fluidPage(

   titlePanel("Google Chart Tools - grafice"),
   sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel(
       selectInput("col", "Selectati coloana dorita", 
                   choices = names(Book1), selected="month")
     ),

     mainPanel(
       htmlOutput("g1"),
       htmlOutput("g2"),
       htmlOutput("g3"),
       htmlOutput("g4"),
       htmlOutput("g5"),
       htmlOutput("g6"),
       htmlOutput("g7"),
       htmlOutput("g8"),
       htmlOutput("g9")
     )
   )

  )

 server <- function(input, output) {

   output$g1 <-renderGvis({
     bk<-Book1[,col("mounth",input$col)]

     gvisPieChart(Book1, 
                  options=list(title="Grafic tip Pie -valori procentuale",
                               colors="['lightgreen', 'lightblue', 'pink','yellow','orange']",
                               width=700, height=500

                  ))
   })

 }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things noted:

- mounth should be 'month'
- for gvisPieChart you want a dataframe that presumably includes month and another column (e.g., apples), so you want to combine those columns: c("month", input$col)
- bk is not referenced in gvisPieChart

Perhaps this might work:

```
output$g1 <- renderGvis ({
    bk <- Book1[, c("month", input$col)]
    gvisPieChart(bk,
                 options=list(title="Grafic tip Pie -valori procentuale",
                              colors="['lightgreen', 'lightblue', 'pink','yellow','orange']",
                              width=700, height=500
                 ))
  })
```